# WPF Web Application Not Showing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, web

I'm a beginner programmer and I have been using WPF in C# to make programs. I have recently read, though, that you can make WPF apps for browsers so I downloaded .net 5 but I still can't make them. When I select new project in visual studio community 2015, it only shows WPF but not WPF Browser. If anyone knows how to get it then please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: You may be looking for Silverlight... but not really clear...

Comment: I don't think it's silverlight. I've seen videos and people will select C# under the new project menu and it will say WPF Web Application. I only have a normal .exe WPF project showing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create a WPF Browser Application:

1. Start Visual Studio.
2. On the **File** menu, point to **New**, and then select **Project**.
   The **New Project** dialog box appears.
3. In the **Installed Templates** pane, expand Visual Basic or Visual C#,
   and then select **Windows**.
4. Above the middle pane, select the target framework from the
   drop-down list.
5. In the middle pane, select the **WPF Browser Application** template.
   Note that the **WPF Browser Application** template in the .NET Framework 4 targets the Client Profile by default. For more information, see .NET Framework Client Profile.
6. In the **Name** text box, specify a name for the project.
7. In the **Location** text box, specify a folder to save the project.
8. Click **OK**. 
   The WPF Designer for Visual Studio opens and displays Page1.xaml of the project.
9. On the **Debug** menu, and select **Start Debugging**.
   A browser window opens and displays the WPF browser application.

Some helpful links:

[**How to: Create a New WPF Browser Application** (the above instructions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628663(v=vs.100).aspx) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628663(v=vs.100).aspx

[**WPF XAML Browser Applications Overview**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970060(v=vs.100).aspx) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970060(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Steps are very much clear from the article from Microsoft. However, the actual question here is the template option "WPF Browser Application" is not visible while trying to create new application. From where can I find it?

Comment: @KasimHusaini That was not the question, so you should read it before down-voting the answer.